# Postion of annotations to lower plot boundary

Tags: r, annotations, plotly

I want to position a text at the bottom of the diagram. Between the line with number.... and the lower plot border should be zero.
I use the following code:

`p22<-p22%>%add_annotations(xref="paper",yref="paper",x=0, y=-0.15,  text=Text_Subtitle,showarrow= F, font=list(size = 10))`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvplB.png)

What do I have to change in the code so that the text ends with the lower plot boundary?

Comment: Try xanchor (values: ['auto', 'left', 'center', 'right']) and yanchor (values: ['auto', 'top', 'middle', 'bottom']): https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/components/annotations/attributes.js

Answer (score 0):

I don’t have all the details, but something similar to this should work:

```
p22<-p22%>%add_annotations(xref="paper",yref="paper",x=0, y=-0.15,  text=Text_Subtitle,showarrow= F, font=list(size = 10), yanchor=“bottom”)
```